# is it worth to decompose big DynamoDB table into multiple tables

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a service which uses DynamoDB as a database. In my service I have a data set about 30 fields. 10 fields are populated by POST API, another fields are populated by 2 PUT APIs. So I consider to decompose these fields into multiple DynamoDB tables and use  [TransactWriteItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactWriteItems.html) to update multiple tables at once when I needed to update more than one table.
Is this approach considered a good practice in DynamoDB or single table is more native DynamoDB approach?

Comment: Use one unless you have a reason to use multiple. What’s your reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "single table design" (actually, a single table plus multiple GSIs which are, under the hood, additional tables) is what most DynamoDB experts recommend. One reason is to be able to do atomic updates without `TransactWriteItems` (which costs you more!). Another reason is to pool the reserved capacity of all your work into one reservation instead of needing to provision multiple tables separately - e.g., imaging that at certain times of the day you'll get a lot of reads/writes to one set of 10 fields, and in other times of the day you get more reads/writes to a different set of 10 fields. Provisioning these tables separately will force you to pay for more slack (unused) capacity.

That being said, having a single table and having a single item is not the same thing: There is a downside to putting all 30 fields in one item, which is that every time you need to read or write to this item - even to just one field - your cost is proportional to the total length of these 30 fields. You can put different sets of fields in different items, even in the same table. If you can, put these items as separate sort keys in the same partition key, to allow you to read the entire item with a single contiguous `Query` instead of multiple small reads (which is more expensive).